# Navbar is jumping

Tags: html, css

When any of the links in the menu is hovered the whole bar just jumping, I can'r figure out what to do((

here is css code, sorry if it's messy, im new to this.

```
.nav{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 48px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.nav li{
    display: inline;
}

.nav a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    font: 25px/1 Courier New, monospace;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 15%; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a:link {color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal;}
a:visited {color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal;}
a:active {color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {font-family: Courier; color: #600080; text-decoration:none; font-weight: none;text-transform: uppercase; position: sticky;}
a:hover { font-size: 215%; }
```

Comment: Add html code too

Comment: plz can you post your html  and why is your font-size:215% ?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is this here:

```
a:hover {
  font-size: 215%;
}
```

As your font-size increases it makes the `a` element larger which makes your `li` and `nav` larger. There's various ways you can address this problem. One of the easiest way is to accommodate for the growth of `a`. If you inspect the element on hover the element becomes `122px` (in my example). If I set a `min-height` the larger `a` size is accommodate for and "shifting" won't occur:

```
a {
  min-height: 130px;
}
```

Now this may not work for you if your links are either dynamic or translatable. You could use `scale` rather than increasing the `font-size` which makes the element grow in place without pushing it's parent's dimension:

```
a:hover {
  transform: scale(2.15);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 48px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  font: 25px/1 Courier New, monospace;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 15%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a:link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:active {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  font-family: Courier;
  color: #600080;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: sticky;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="">Nav Link One</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Nav Link Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Nav Link Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Nav Link Four</a></li>
</ul>
```